# Firebase : pagination with multiple 'orderBy' and 'orderBy' with FieldPath.documentId()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I will test a request like this

```
 let ref = firestore().collection(COLLECTION)
 ref = ref.where('date', "in", ['01/01/2022', '02/01/2022'])
 ref = ref.where('valueP', '>', 12)
 ref = ref.where('valueP', '<', 32
 ref = ref.orderBy('valueP')

if (filterType) {
  ref = ref.where('product.type', '==', filterType) // filterType is a string variable
}
if (filterCategory) {
  ref = ref.where('product.category', '==', filterCategory) // filterCategory is a string variable
}

// pagination
ref = ref.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'asc')
if (paginationStart) {
  ref = ref.startAfter(paginationStart)   // paginationStart is a documentid
}
ref = ref.limit(10)

ref.get()
```

In the first time , my request work. I have 10 documents.

I save my last document id in the variable 'paginationStart'.   It's ok

In the second time , my request have the filter 'startAfter'  but i have the same data like the first time.

I had something wrong with the filter 'startAfter' ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: "paginationStart" is the last document not document id

Comment: @JafarJabr , it's my last document id  for my example ( 4rGDPbDfU3a2qZvvtGG2 )

Comment: their documentation saying that it has to be the entire document not only the id,
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query

Comment: ahhhh ok yes i test and it's work but ... 
i have a problem with this the last document , redux doesn't work ahah 
redux-persist/createPersistoid: error serializing state [TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.] ....    I must keep all the document like the example of the document ?

Comment: I suggest to save the last document in the service or whatever you use before to send it to redux

Comment: @JafarJabr That sounds like an answer, so please post below so that others can also more easily find it (and OP and others can upvote it). 

Comment: For a simple solution.   
i retrieve the last document , save in the constant , and update my constante if my pagination is updated.   thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase documentation suggest the startAfter to be the entire document not only the document id

more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query)

Comment: @roplopfan Worth also mentioning that `startAfter` in both the [modern](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#startafter_2) and [legacy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query#startafter) SDKs can take a list of key-value pairs (corresponding to the `orderBy` restrictions) rather than the full document too. So for the above query, you'd use `startAfter("valueP", lastValueP, firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), lastDocumentId)`